# What are the risks of allowing general users to add printers to their company laptops?

Tags: risk, printers, driver

I work for a company with a large user base. There is a requirement to allow users to add printers to their laptops e.g. when working from home.

What are the security risks?
Is their a bad actor can use a printer to hack the laptop?
Can a print driver elevate privileges and causes something bad to happen?

Comment: I believe stuxnet used the Windows printer system as a vector to exploit systems. Historically it has had a lot of exploits that lead to privilege escalation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent [PrintNightmare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PrintNightmare) attack takes advantage of printer driver installation, and one of the mitigations Microsoft has put in place is to restrict the ability to install printer drivers to Administrators.  So, yes, a bad actor can hack a laptop if regular users are allowed to install print drivers.  And apparently limiting it to Administrators is not wholly sufficient:

> Researchers have noted that the vulnerability has not been fully
> addressed by the patches. After the patch is applied, only
> administrators will be able to install printer drivers on a Windows
> print server, as part of the vulnerability related to the ability of
> non-administrators to install printer drivers on the system.